# Preventing content to overflow through a dropdown menu of fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**What I'm trying**

I want to fix the width of dropdown menu *i.e.* `ul.dropdown-menu` in Bootstrap.

**Bug**

If a list-item has a long content, it overflows through the dropdown menu.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/96fwK/

**Code**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3" style="width:400px;">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <!-- Below is the buggy list-item -->
    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">A very long content overflows 
            the list-item if ul.dropdown-menu's width is fixed
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the first line, I aded `style="width:400px;"`. Rest all is the Bootstrap's normal syntax.

**How it looks**

[image: The content overflows through <code>list-item</code> on fixing <code>ul.dropdown-menus</code>'s width]

**How I want it to look**

I want the long content to break into new lines so that it looks just like this:

[image: Preventing the content to overflow and making it look like this]

**What I've tried**

All these didn't work.

1. Added `display: block;` to the *buggy* `li` (the one through which the content is overflowing) and to the `<a>` tang inside it.
2. `word-break` to the *buggy* `li` and `<a>`.
3. `max-width` to the *buggy* `li` and `<a>`.
4. Adding `display: table;` to `ul.dropdown-menu` removes its dropdown functionality and causes its width to increase so as to wrap the *buggy* `li` completely.
5. Added a `<div style="display:block;>"` inside the *buggy* `li` to wrap the content.
6. `display: block !important;` to the *buggy* `li`.
7. Adding `display: block; to`ul.dropdown-menu` also removes dropdown functionality.
8. I also searched for answers on SO and Google.

**What I don't want**

1. To truncate the content and add ellipsis.
2. To add a scroll-bar or hide the content.

Comment: Can you remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from the `.dropdown-menu>li>a`? or set `white-space: normal;` to the `<a>`.

Comment: @Ex-iT Awesome! Totally works. Thanks. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it works! @user3253746 Posted it as an answer now, thanks :)

Comment: All the answers are correct (and same). Unfortunately, I can't mark all of them as _accepted answers_. So I'll go with Ex-iT's answer since he was the first to answer my question (although in comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from the `.dropdown-menu>li>a`? or set `white-space: normal;` to the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is the white-space property on the a tag:

```
  .dropdown-menu > li > a {white-space:normal}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" style="word-wrap:break-all">
    A very long content overflows the list-item if ul.dropdown-menu's width is fixed
</a>
```

With this:

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" style="white-space:normal">
    A very long content overflows the list-item if ul.dropdown-menu's width is fixed
</a>
```

[White-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is pretty helpful, I like white-space.